# Next Halving BlockChain BlockNumber?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

Hello every hope **all are good** ?

I'm asking where can you get the block halving number from a BlockChain ?

Is there a way in **web3** ?

Can i find it in **WhitePaper** for each BlockChain ?
Need i check block **reward** ?

I find many answer for **Bitcoin BlockChain** but i want know for **other** like Polygon or Binance or Avax ...

How proceed it please ?

Sincerely Mike

Answer (score 1):

Halving is a concept that doesn't exist for all  chains, it's actually specific to bitcoin, to my knowledge. Maybe some other blockchains have that (bitcoin hardforks such as BCH probably do, maybe some other lesser known chains do too). Bitcoin's block rewards get halved every 210000 blocks, but for the other examples you gave (Polygon, Bsc and Avalanche) there's no such thing. BNB, for example, does not have block rewards at all (no BNB is generated when a new block is mined on the BSC)

Comment: Where to find other with same protocol as Bitcoin ?

Comment: You'd have to check for every protocol individually, i don't think there's someone out there maintaining a list of every blockchain that has that halving concept, if that's your question

Answer (score 0):

Block halving is specific for Bitcoin (and some less known blockchains)

But not every blockchain has it. ETH, AVAX, BNB, etc don't have block-halvings. Best thing to do is do a general research on blockchains you are interested into.

Hope this helps,  good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answer, no other way only reseach  do you have something to share about next other halkving  ? or in web3 cmd etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

**I fund list on 2 website** with multiple **blockchain halving** but please share more link please:

[**https://www.nicehash.com/countdown**](https://www.nicehash.com/countdown)

[**https://halvingdates.com**](https://www.nicehash.com/countdown)